# How to print the msg_content in textview android json here?

Tags: android, json

```
{
    "status": "ERROR", 
    "msg_content": "Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again.",
    "code": "400", 
    "msg_title": "Sorry. Error in processing your request"
}

if (str.startsWith("Bad Request"))
{
    textview.setText(" ");                          
}
```

How to print inside the textview to display the `msg_content` using json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse json using JSON object.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

Then find string from JSON object whatever you want.

```
if (obj.has("msg_content")) {
         String value = obj.getString("msg_content");
         textview.settext(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a JSONObject and pass it the string as a parameter.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

Then to find a key in the JSONObject just call, always check if the JSONObject has that key before trying to retrieve it.

```
if (obj.has("status"){
   String status = obj.getString("status");
}

if (obj.has("msg_content"){
   String content = obj.getString("msg_content");
   textview.setText(content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JsonReader is implemented in API 11. If you want to use it in GingerBread or below try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use following Code for extracting Information from JSON Objects:

```
try {         
          Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) keys.next();
                if(key.equals("msg_content"))
                    textView.setText(jsonObject.getString(key));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also, if u have JSON as String, u can populate an object using following code:

```
try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(theJsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to JSON but I would create a JsonReader and parse the JSON as per [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)